# Delete last 10 days data Through batch class

Tags: apex, batch, salesforce-id, schedulebatch

How to delete last 10 days data using batch class I am Trying to using below code but data not deleted please check and give me suggestion to acheive this requirement.

```
global class ExampleBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
 global ExampleBatchClass(){

   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        Date s = system.today()-10;
        string query = 'select id  from Account where createDdate <:S';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account>scope){
          if(scope.size>0)
    delete scope;
  }
 global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

   }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, `if(scope.size>0)` line tells me, that your code can't be compiled successfully, because `size()` is method of `List`, not property

second, use [date literal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) `LAST_N_DAYS:n` to select

> For the number n provided, starts 00:00:00 of the current day and
>   continues for the past n days.

third, condtiion `if(scope.size()>0)` can be skipped

finally your code will look like

```
global class ExampleBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    global ExampleBatchClass(){
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            select Id
            from Account
            where CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:10
            ]);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account>scope){
        delete scope;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```